# Moving the score on the top of posts?

Tags: feature-request, design

I noticed that the score of answers and questions, together with the "favorite question" star, that used to be on the left margin, is now shown on the top of each post. May I say that I can't see the advantage of this change? On the other hand, occupying the space between posts makes it more difficult to read more of them on the same screen. And requires more paper, in case one needs to print them. So why changing?

Comment: Please update your browser to a version which supports grid layout.

Comment: Please include your browser and OS details in the question, for design issues it's critical.